# CSeq INVITE sip request 1 and 2

Tags: sip, voip

why we have CSeq: 1 INVITE and CSeq: 2 INVITE
what is for request
Who will give me the correct response

why we have CSeq: 1 INVITE and CSeq: 2 INVITE
what is for request
Who will give me the correct response
some servers like cisco
can invite just CSeq: 1 not need 2
and some servers need 1 and need 2

What is the way to make me distinguish if I need to invite 2 or not

Comment: I think you'd best read RFC3261. That will explain you how to use and interpret CSEQ and much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSeq or Command Sequence contains an integer and a method name. The CSeq number is incremented for each new dialog request and is a traditional sequence number.

Nothing fancy, just a sequence number incremented as you can see with `CSEQ 1 INVITE` and `CSEQ 2 INVITE`, if I assume you are receiving two INVITE on the same dialogue then just respond to the last CSEQ, in that case `CSEQ 2 INVITE`.
Logically, it is just a retransmission, you do not have to answer to both only the last received one.

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend, for a beautiful and persuasive speech

Comment: A request with CSeq 2 is NOT a retransmission of a request with CSeq 1. Retransmissions will have the same CSeq value. So you will have to respond to both.

Comment: You are right in theory, both invite should be treated.   I think it is a different case even if the description is vague, it looks like two re-invite are received with updated headers. Now maybe I am wrong.